# how to end an array from a list of questions

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list of questions which is in an array and when a button is clicked on the interface it will move on to the next question but when its at the last question it will switch to a summary page and display a score of correct answers. when the array gets to the last question it throws an "argument out of range exception was unhandled". how would I get the array to stop so it can continue after the last question ?

this is the method I have for moving on to the next question

thanks for any help and let me know if you need to see anymore of the code.

Comment: show us some code where the array is used. you're probably just tryig to access an element that isnt there

Comment: That code is irrelevant. Show us where you use the array, thats where the exception is.

Comment: What is the code in `displayQuestion()`? I assume there are 20 questions.

Comment: yes there is 20 questions

Comment: Post your code in `displayQuestion()`, that is *probably* where the error is originating.

Comment: bonus points to whoever can answer all 20 questions

Comment: Why not use a foreach loop to go through all the questions if it is a List (or any IEnumerable)?

Answer (score 5):

Use this condition. I am assuming your array has 20 items and since your condition is > 20 it breaks on index. when you try to access array[20]th element as arrays are `zero` indexed.

```
if (questionNumber >= qu.Count)
```

Comment: yeah this is probably the issue

Comment: Can you check in debug mode what is the length of your array?

Comment: or better yet, `questionNumber >= questions.Length`

Comment: @user2311854 where are you incrementing the `questionNumber`

Comment: @NominSim Thanks for the edit, so he is using a GenericList instead of an array.

Comment: `foreach (var q in qu) { DisplayQuestion(); }`  `NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/summary_page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));`

Comment: with the if (questionNumber >= qu.Count) still throws the error

Comment: @PSCoder: Ya I guess that makes sense.

Comment: it wont seem to work with that but I appreciate all the help guys

Comment: @MrCode I would suggest you to debug through your code carefully and see where the `questionNumber` is getting incremented. and when it throws the error check what is the `questionNumber`. This should give a clue. Also make sure you are not deleting any item from the List.

Comment: @MrCode: You may need to post more code, or step through the code via the debugger and find the exact line that is catching the error.

Answer (score 5):

I'd consider using a foreach loop and slightly redesigning your solution to the following:

```
public void DisplayQuestion(Question q)
{
    txt_block_question.Text = qu.question;
    btn_Answer_A.Content = q.a;
    btn_Answer_B.Content = q.b;
    btn_Answer_C.Content = q.c;
 }

public void DisplaySummary()
{
    foreach (var q in qu)
    {
        DisplayQuestion(qu);
    }

    NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/summary_page.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
}
```

The foreach will take care of the indexing for you. Passing in each question to display is also better than relying on some shared variable.

Comment: thanks ive never used this method before but will certainly give it a try

Comment: @user2311854: You may have to modify this a bit since you are likely waiting for an answer to be chosen and possibly a next button. Otherwise it'll just rip through the questions and jump to the summary.